# git commit in vsts build through powershell does not work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-tfs

I am trying to push a test file during a ci build on vsts. However, it seems that the commit command does not work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The screen capture you show doesn't seem to sync up very well with the commands in your script.  I don't see anything wrong with what you did, so an error message is the only thing which might tip us off as to what the problem is.

Comment: You haven't configured git in that repo yet. So you can't commit namelessly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just re-ran the build and made sure the task is saved.Same result,  such error is out of the question now...

Comment: @tehhowch you are right I have set the following: 

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

And it worked
If you will provide an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: All I did was read the error message, which you were supposed to do ;)

Comment: @tehhowch I assumed that if I can pull and push without a name configured. Why shouldn't commit work. Assumption is the mother of all ...

Comment: @Igor there's a big difference between loading the work of others and creating work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tehhowch commented below the question. It is impossible to commit without your username/name configured for the local git configuration.

It can be solved as shown in the error message =), by using:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
git config --global user.name
```